# Sum of n probabilities times the sum of their corresponding values giving total expected value mathematically sound?

Tags: probability, statistics

I am currently creating a model for my high school class and have come across this problem. (sorry for bad title- can't explain without details)

So let's say I have people coming over, and there is a 0.1 probability that 1 person comes over, 0.2 probability that 2 people come over, and a 0.3 probability that 3 people come over.

So is it mathematically allowed to add the probabilities and multiply it by the sum of their values?

(0.1+0.2+0.3)*(1+2+3) = 3.6, which would mean that given these probabilities, 3.6 people are expected to show up? Does this make sense? It agrees with intuition and I have been thinking about it with thought experiments but I am not sure if it actually makes sense.

Comment: How could the expected number of people exceed the maximum possible?

Comment: The formula you want is $E=\sum i\times p_i$  where for $i\in \{0,1,2,\cdots \}$ $p_i$ denotes the probability that exactly $i$ people show up.  Now your probabilities do not sum to $1$ so are we to assume that the missing probability is $p_0$?

Comment: Format maths like a pro with our [guide to MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: If the probability no one comes over is .4 then you have probabilities $p = (.4, .1, .2, .3),$ of counts $x = (0, 1, 2, 3).$ Then the p's sum to 1. In R statistical software and other programs, multiplication of vectors `*` is elementwise. So statements `p = c(.4, .1, .2, .3);` `x = 0:3;` and `sum(p*x)` return `1.4`, which is the mean number of people to arrive.

Answer (score 1):

You need to multiply each quantity by its respective probability before adding. In this example, that's: $0.1\cdot 1 + 0.2\cdot 2 + 0.3\cdot 3 +\cdots$

This will give you the expected value, but only if you have a full list of possible events, so that the probabilities, on their own, sum to $1$. If you just add the probabilities, and add the events, and *then* multiply, then you'll just get a sum of possible events, which as noted in a comment, is larger than any possible event, defying common sense.

Comment: Seems we're all assuming the purpose is to find the expectation, but that is not stated explicitly except in the header. Nice try to make sense of an imprecise tangle. (+1)